# Where can I find London borough outlines for SPLAT!

Tags: antenna-modeling

[Splat](https://www.qsl.net/kd2bd/splat.html) seems like it's a great tool for modelling what RF coverage I should have. It can create a nice circle around me, after I download topology data from USGS, namely SRTM-1.

But when the coverage map (created using `-L 17`) gets created it looks kind of like the logo on the Splat home page, which means I can't tell what's where on the map anymore.

Is there data for London (UK) I can overlay to make it clearer? I think I'm looking for cartographic boundary data. So it's [this](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london)? But how do I convert it to the format that Splat wants?

Comment: Don't know about data formats and SPLAT, but here's another good source of geodata that may or may not contain what you need: https://gadm.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that had the data I needed. The KML file was easily convertible to the format needed:
N x y
x y
x y
END
M x y
x y
END
(where N and M are indexes, so "1" and "2" for this tiny example)
That draws up the polygon.
If you upgrade this to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it was useful! I've added a short answer. Perhaps it would be helpful to add more details about the format conversion, but you'd have to contribute that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GADM](https://gadm.org/index.html) is an online project aspiring to provide maps and spatial data for all countries of the world and their administrative subdivisions at all levels. It also contains outlines of London boroughs. According to the asker, the KMZ file provided by GADM is easily convertible to the format required by Splat.